# Is SystemModStamp field comparable to variables of DateTime data type in SOQL statements?

Tags: apex, soql

I have a field on a custom setting which is of the type DateTime. I have a business requirement where I need to use this value in conditional SOQL of one SObject.

If I try to use `Select Id, myField__c FROM MySampleObject__c WHERE SystemModStamp > myDateTimeValue` , the SOQL statement throws compile time error.

Is it some data type issue or is it not comparable to variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is comparable with DateTime variables, you just forgot colon that bind variables need in SOQL:

```
Select Id, myField__c FROM MySampleObject__c WHERE SystemModStamp > :myDateTimeValue
```

> [Notice that in the query, the bind variable is preceded by a colon ( : ).](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/soql-for-admins/use-bind-variables-and-aggregate-functions)

Comment: Ah, that was such a simple miss. Thanks. This solved the issue.